# Google charts - when Y range is changed, graph doesn't scale correctly

Tags: scaling, google-visualization

I'm using a simple Google chart to picture a benchmark:
[image]

Since most data is located between 50 and 100 I tried to make the range a bit smaller but this results in an incorrect graph.
[image]

**First value of the red line starts at 72 on first graph but at 87 on the second one**. The HTML code looks like the following:

```
<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxr=0,50,100|1,0,50&chxt=y,x&chs=900x300&cht=ls&chco=DA3B15,3072F3&chd=s:stt3rp3ts7rp2ut7uz7tt5rr5rw5rs2qr2qr2tq5rr3qp3rr2q,uqq2sp0nqnzoop3qq2tt4tr2sr2rw1rq2rr2qs3pozpoo4rp2p&chdl=With+lock|Without+lock&chg=50,20&chls=2|2&chtt=FluorineFx+-+FactoryInstance+with%2Fwithout+lock&chts=676767,13" width="1000" height="300" alt="FluorineFx - FactoryInstance with/without lock" />
```

Has anyone a solution that helps scaling the graph correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work I had to change the input data to plain data format to:

```
chd=t:72,73,... // char data
```

Define the required range for the axis ranges:

```
chxr=0,60,100,10|1,0,50,5
```

Specify the char custom scaling value:

```
chds=60,100
```

Which results in:

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=900x300&amp;cht=ls&amp;chd=t:72,73,73,90,71,68,90,73,72,97,71,68,88,76,74,97,76,84,96,74,74,94,70,70,94,71,78,93,71,72,89,69,70,89,69,70,88,74,69,94,71,71,90,69,68,90,71,70,89,69|75,69,69,89,72,67,85,64,69,64,84,65,65,67,90,69,69,89,73,73,92,74,70,88,72,70,88,71,78,87,70,69,88,70,71,88,69,72,90,68,65,84,67,66,66,91,71,68,89,68&amp;chxt=y,x&chds=60,100&amp;chxr=0,60,100,10|1,0,50,5&amp;chbh=35&chg=10,10&chco=DA3B15,3072F3&chdl=With+lock|Without+lock&chtt=FluorineFx+-+FactoryInstance+with%2Fwithout+lock"/>
```

[image]